# Multipy metric with SUM

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I want to multiply a metric with the outcome of the sum of another metric

What I want to try to do:

```
MeticOne * SUM(MetricTwo)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose you have `MetricOne` with labels `id` and `name`. And you have `MetricTwo` with labels also `id` and `name`. Then you have the sum of values from `MetricTwo` aggregated by `id` using the metric:

```
sum without (name) (MetricTwo)
```

You can do a "join" in prometheus using the `on(id)` together with the `group_left`:

```
MetricOne 
* on (id) group_left() 
(sum without (name) (MetricTwo))
```

This is only possible if the label `id` from `MetricOne` is also `id` on the `MetricTwo` that you are joining. So, if they are different you may see an empty result query although there are rows to match!

**Improvement:**

Then it comes the time when you need to use `label_replace` to rename the label of one metric and make it match with the label of the other metric. Let's say that `MetricOne` with labels `metric_one_id` and `name` and we want to relabel it to `id`. You have to do this:

```
label_replace(MetricOne,"id","$1","metric_one_id", "(.+)")
```

Then you can use the same previous operator of before:

```
label_replace(MetricOne,"id","$1","metric_one_id", "(.+)") 
* on (metric_one_id) group_left() 
(sum without (name) (MetricTwo))
```

Regarding the `group_left()`, everything inside the `group_left()` will be excluded on the result. So in case you have more labels you might add them in the `group_left()` or on the `without()`. The Prometheus documentation explains the `group_left` operator [here](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#many-to-one-and-one-to-many-vector-matches).